# C#: Drawing scatter plot on MS-Charts

Tags: c#, mschart

This is my code:

```html
private void DrawCharts()
        {
            List<double> xAxis = new List<double>();
            List<double> yAxis = new List<double>();

            ch_Vf2.Series.Add("Vf2");
            ch_Vf2.Series["Vf2"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
            foreach (Value v in Bf1_Values["Vf2"].Values)
            {
                xAxis.Add(v.d_val);
            }

            foreach (Value v in Bf2_Values["Vf2"].Values)
            {
                yAxis.Add(v.d_val);
            }

            ch_Vf2.Series["Vf2"].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis.ToArray(), yAxis.ToArray());
        }
```

The result is the following:

[image]

**Questions**

1. How can I contain all the points within the Chart grid areas, as some points are outside?
2. How do I set the best fit line?
3. How can I set the gridline and maximum axis values?
4. How do I set axis names and plot names?

Comment: What do you mean by _some points are outside_? I see none! Also: Once you have set ther Minimum and maximum points indeed may go outside those values. Either keep them automatic or make them large enough or live with it. axes are ChartArea properties, incl. Min., Max. and titles. - Finally: You will have to calculate the best-fit line. Also: Only one question per post here!